# Schedule scale in and out of Instances in Autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

We have an Autoscaling group that scales up in the morning and down at night. However we would like to be able to scale up and down whenever we like during the day. We would like to do this in an automated way so that the ASG sets itself to 0/0/0 and then we can use the same automation to scale up to our desired capacity if someone needs it
Does anyone know if this is possible in an ASG? I know the ASG has scheduler option, predictive etc but I'd like to do this using CloudFormation, or Lambda etc

Comment: What do you mean by "do this in an automated way"? How will it know whether to add/remove instances during the day? You can set the **Desired Capacity** of an Auto Scaling group and it will Launch/Terminate instances to match that number.

Comment: We already have our AGS scale up each morning and scale down at night but we would like to some sort of automation we can use to do the same whenever we like without using the GUI
We tend to not use the GUI in AWS if we can help it. Therefore just investigating if we can use some sort of automation to target our ASG based on its tags so we can scale it on demand. Like using Lambda for example

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could use the Auto Scaling group to provide your desired number of instances:

You can use **Scaling Policies** where the Auto Scaling group evaluates metrics and launches/terminates instances to meet those metrics. For example, it could use **average CPU Utilization** amongst the instances, or even **custom metrics** that your application generates, such as the number of simultaneous users. See: [Dynamic scaling for Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html)

Alternatively, you can manage the scaling logic *external* to Auto Scaling and then simply tell Auto Scaling to set the **Desired Capacity** to a certain number of instances. It will then launch/terminate instances to reach that target capacity, similar to how you currently have it scaling on a schedule. See: [Manual scaling for Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-manual-scaling.html)

Comment: That would work but ultimately we would prefer some type of automation so anytime we want to scale up or down we dont need to use the GUI. Instead at any given time of the day we can simply trigger an automation to scale up to a desired max or down to zero

Comment: I'm confused by your use of the word "automation", which suggests that something should happen 'automatically', yet you say that you would then "trigger an automation", which suggests a manual activity. Could you please clarify your actual requirement? Should it happen without human involvement, or would the human 'trigger' the scaling manually?